# PyMongo query with projection

Tags: pymongo

what is the PyMongo way for  db.collection.find(criteria, projection).I cant find any doc for specifying  projection to the collection.find() method

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Is equeal to `mongo shell`, but the **[condition](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/)** between `""`

```
db.foo.find({"field1.field2":123},{"field1":{"$elemMatch":{"field2":123}}})

db.foo.update({"_id":3,"field1.field2":1},{"$set":{"field1.$.field2":2}})
```

Or if you mean to projections to show any fields, is equal to `mongo shell`

```
db.foo.find({"field1.field2":123},{"field1.field2":1, "_id":1})
```

Comment: Here a put an example, with variable interpolation, very useful in Python, and also useful for situations where you have a object stored in a variable, that you want to use in your projection, for example, and object with data from a state of USA stored on `var_state` variable:
`db.foo.find({"country":"USA" }, {f"states.{var_state}": 1, "_id": False})`

Answer (score 3):

projection (optional): a list of field names that should be returned in the result set or a dict specifying the fields to include or exclude. If projection is a list “_id” will always be returned. Use a dict to exclude fields from the result (e.g. projection={‘_id’: False}).

Find more from [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I found working:
db['collection'].find(filter={fieldZ: '..'}, projection={'fieldA': 1, 'fieldB': 1})

From pyMongo documentation https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html

--- Look for function 'find

Full parameter list from doc:

find(filter=None, projection=None, skip=0, limit=0, no_cursor_timeout=False, cursor_type=CursorType.NON_TAILABLE, sort=None, allow_partial_results=False, oplog_replay=False, batch_size=0, collation=None, hint=None, max_scan=None, max_time_ms=None, max=None, min=None, return_key=False, show_record_id=False, snapshot=False, comment=None, session=None, allow_disk_use=None)